# Facebook Php SDK - Can't access user's feed through extended access tocken

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am developing a Facebook app which will need to read the posts of all the
users    who have authenticated the app.   The "posts reading script" will run through corn 
and will get all the posts from the users no matter they are online or offline. I have been 
trying to solve this problem for 1 week but with no fruitful results. here is my code

```
function index()
{

    $this->load->model("proofreader"); //my scanner
    $this->load->library('email'); //library for sending emails
    $this->facebook->setExtendedAccessToken($this->facebook->getAccessToken());


    $i = 0;

    foreach ($users as $rows) //$users is an array containing data from users
    {
        $i++;

        $posts = $this->facebook->api('/' . $rows[$i] . '/posts');
        $this->proofreader->read($posts);
        if ($this->proofreader->returnresults()) { /*do appropriate functions*/
        }


    }

}
```

All i want to do it is this:

A way to read all the posts of a user who has authenticated the app and is offline.

Please correct me what's wrong with the above script or if you can, direct me to any alternative. I have read the Facebook documentations more than a 1000 times last week.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: is it that tough? No answers :(

Comment: ask the nsa, this sounds like their domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I need an extended access token to access user's posts while he/she is offline. Else , It will return only the actions of the users and not the messages. furthermore, i need to ask for read_stream permissions while authenticating the app